# What is the easiest way of getting multiple database queries into Excel?

Tags: sql, excel, ssms

I have around 10 SQL SELECT statements that I run against SQL Server.  Each resultset that is returned needs to go into its own Excel sheet (though same excel file).

Sure, I can copy and paste each result set from SQL Server Management Studio into Excel manually, but there has to be a better way.

So short of writing my own program, is there an easier way?

Comment: Not that I know of. When I've done this in the past, I wrote a program to add sheets dynamically based on resultsets returned

Comment: Writing a VBA program to do this is quite trivial. 10-15 minutes tops.

Comment: There is a whole web site dedicated to this problem www.excel-sql-server.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a little command line app that does this very thing.  I've posted the code on [github](https://github.com/rgelb/Database-to-Excel).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need macros to do this, you can query your SQL server directly from Excel and create 10 independent connections. Once you have your connections, you add them to separate sheets or "tabs" by selecting the "Existing Connections" option in the Data menu. It will ask you where you want to "dump" the dataset. Once you do this x10, you can Refresh all and you will have the most recent data. Here is a how to:

[LInk](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/connect-to-import-sql-server-data-HA010217956.aspx)

The only change here is instead of selecting "Table", you select SQL from the Command type and paste your SQL query in the Command Text box.

Comment: Well, there are advantages to this method. A.- Each connection can be created in less than one minute, so you have a working "solution" in about 5-10 mins. B.- You can change your queries independently. C.- You can create Pivot Tables and Charts directly in Excel and refresh them "automagically" which at the end I'm pretty sure he will need.

Comment: Create one external data connection on one sheet and copy that sheet nine times. The connection will copy but the connection string will be the same. Then go into each of those nine new sheets and put whatever SQL string you want. Slightly faster than creating 10 independently, I think.